# getting size harddisk with fseek()

Tags: size, hard-drive, fseek

I have been trying to get the harddisk size on linux systems using fseek().

I have a function which should return the correct size:

```
unsigned long long getsize(FILE *fp){
    unsigned long long prev=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    unsigned long long size=ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,prev,SEEK_SET);
    return size;
}
```

But when I use it on a harddisk it returns 18446744073709551615 or 2^64-1...

it doesn't seem to always return it. as I can use it on files fine. I also has worked before on harddisks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this sort of results because that's not the right way to get the disk size.

If you want to check the size of disk you should issue an ioctl() on disk fd with a request of BLKGETSIZE64 (and argument of pointer to long long).

```
long long disk_size;
ioctl(<disk_fd>, BLKGETSIZE64, &disk_size);
```

If you're rather interested in filesystem size (which may be different) or empty space on a filesystem then use `statvfs()` call.

Comment: thank you this worked! I have another question if fseek is not allowed then. I am working on a little script which checks for certain bytes at certain offsets on the harddisk. Can I use fseek and fread for that?

Comment: seek will probably work, but if you're only checking for some values why not use pread()/fread()?

Comment: its reading data sector by sector, and I specify the offsets mathematically so its easier to use fseek then fread